# If $X$ is a random vector, and $Y = BX$, prove that $|d(y)/d(x)| = \det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, random-variables

I am trying to prove the following:

If $\mathbf{X}$ is a random vector and $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{BX}$, then
$$
\left|\frac{d(\mathbf{y})}{d(\mathbf{x})}\right| = \det \mathbf{B}.
$$

I am not really sure where to start, I have tried to assume that $\mathbf{B}$ must be of the form
$$
\mathbf{B}_{n\times n} = \begin{bmatrix}
B_1 & \cdots & B_n\\
0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
since I don't otherwise know what to make of $\det \mathbf{B}$, but
then $\det \mathbf{B}$ is always zero and clearly not equal to
$\left|\frac{d(\mathbf{y})}{d(\mathbf{x})}\right|$. Can anybody help me out?

*Note: This is exercise 5.1 from Allan Gut: An Intermediate Course in Probability, but is not homework.*

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{d(y)}{d(x)}$ here?

Comment: I took it for granted that it is the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, but it is not specified. I just realized that it is supposed to be $|d(y)/d(x)|$. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Note that if $f\,:\,\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ is a linear function $f(x)=Bx$ then indeed, the derivative of $f$ is $B$ and its determinant or Jacobian is thus, $\left|\frac{df}{dx}\right|=\det(B)$. What I am still missing here is the dependency of $\frac{d(y)}{d(x)}$ on the realization $\omega\in \Omega$.